# Instafeed Script Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been developing a website that requires an instagram feed. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work! Here's what I've done.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    feed = new Instafeed({
    clientId: '99808b1edfc140eda1cfa2dca4b4fe4c',
    accessToken: '201047212.467ede5.1072e8c882e34a8fb7975f725e7b3ba8',
    get: 'user',
    userId: 201047212,
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    links: 'false',
    template: '<div id="instafeed-caption">{{caption}} <br>&hearts; {{likes}} on <a href="{{link}}" class="sky">instagram</a></div><div id="instafeed-container"><img src="{{image}}" /></div>',
    mock: true,
    custom: {
    images: [],
    currentImage: 0,
    showImage: function () {
    var result, image;
    image = this.options.custom.images[this.options.custom.currentImage];
    result = this._makeTemplate(this.options.template, {
    model: image,
    id: image.id,
    link: image.link,
    image: image.images[this.options.resolution].url,
    caption: this._getObjectProperty(image, 'caption.text'),
    likes: image.likes.count,
    comments: image.comments.count,
    location: this._getObjectProperty(image, 'location.name')
  });
  (function($){ 
    $("#instafeed").html(result)
  })
}
  },
  success: function (data) {
    this.options.custom.images = data.data; 
    this.options.custom.showImage.call(this);
  }
});
feed.run();

(function($){
  $(".instafeed-next").click(function () {
    var length, current;
    current = feed.options.custom.currentImage;
    length = feed.options.custom.images.length;
if (current < length - 1) {
  feed.options.custom.currentImage++;
  feed.options.custom.showImage.call(feed);
}
  })
});

(function($){
  $(".instafeed-prev").click(function () {
    var length, current;
    current = feed.options.custom.currentImage;
    length = feed.options.custom.images.length;
    if (current > 0) {
      feed.options.custom.currentImage--
      feed.options.custom.showImage.call(feed);
    }
  })
});
</script>
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone could tell me what is wrong with the script. I pulled it off an example on the Instafeed website. For reference, the website is [www.hemeon.com](http://www.hemeon.com). My website is [www.vcluxe.nu/contact-me](http://www.vcluxe.nu/contact-me). Thanks!

Comment: Looks like someone is trying to treat an asynchronous call as synchronous.

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm not very good with jQuery; could you tell me what is wrong with the script? It works for him - not sure why it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

oh hey.. i don't know about all that code you have... but something the instafeed page does NOT seem to mention...is to add a "limit"...this tells instagram how many images to drop in.. otherwise i suppose the default is zero...

I made mine: **limit: '4'**

would be a pretty helpful piece of info to put into the instructions!

see below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'cool',
        clientId: '916c01b8624d43c7b4b76369aruc86a0',
        limit: '4' 
    });
    feed.run(); </script>
```